# Add padding RSA PKCS#1 after hash SHA256 and before calling API of signature

Tags: c#, hash, padding, pkcs#1

In order to use a certificate stored in a distant HSM (using cloud signature), I'm actually trying to use an API that generates a PKCS#1.5 signature given a SHA256 Hash. The problem is that the specification of the protocol that I need to implement states that the padding process must be in PKCS#1.

The encryption algorithm supported by the API is this OID : RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 encryption scheme

http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.1

Here is the specification of the protocol, it is stated the the padding process must be PKCS#1 :

[image: Padding specification]

The developers of the API mentioned that if I'm able to pad the hash value generated before sending the hash to the API, I would be able to generate the right signature.

Here is the explanation of the process :

[image]

But I can't find any way of padding the hash after it's generated and before it's sent to the API.

```
...

string pathFileToBeHashed = "D:\\Temp\\virsct.SCT";

// Gets content of file
// Removes invalid characters before hash

string strToHash = File.ReadAllText(pathFileToBeHashed);
strToHash = strToHash.Replace(Constants.vbCr, "");
strToHash = strToHash.Replace(Constants.vbLf, "");
strToHash = strToHash.Replace(Strings.ChrW(26).ToString(), "");

// Hash SHA256

byte[] btToHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strToHash);
string strHashed = string.Empty;

using var sha256 = new SHA256Managed()
{
    strHashed = Convert.ToBase64String(sha256.ComputeHash(btToHash));
}

// Send to the API

...
```

When I personally check the signature using the following code after the hash is being signed, the result is OK. The method that I'm using to check signature is as above.

```
private static bool IsSignatureOK(string certB64, string signB64, string strCheminCompletFichier)
{
    X509Certificate2 x509 = null;
    try
    {
        x509 = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certB64));

        using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] btSign = Convert.FromBase64String(signB64);

        byte[] btFichier = File.ReadAllBytes(strCheminCompletFichier);
        byte[] btHashFichier = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(btFichier))
        {
            btHashFichier = CalculateHash(ms);
        }

        return rsa.VerifyHash(btHashFichier, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), btSign);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Interaction.MsgBox($"KO : {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (x509 != null)
            x509.Reset();
    }
}

public static byte[] CalculateHash(MemoryStream memStream)
{
    byte[] btHashWithContext = null;

    int BLOC_LENGTH = 1000000;

    memStream.Position = 0;

    int Nb_Blocs = Convert.ToInt32(memStream.Length / BLOC_LENGTH) + (memStream.Length % BLOC_LENGTH == 0 ? 0 : 1);

    using (SHA256Managed hashAlgorithm = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        byte[] MyBuffer = null;
        for (int j = 0; j <= Nb_Blocs - 1; j++)
        {
            MyBuffer = new byte[BLOC_LENGTH];

            int Nb_octets_lus = memStream.Read(MyBuffer, 0, BLOC_LENGTH);
            if (Nb_octets_lus != BLOC_LENGTH)
                Array.Resize(ref MyBuffer, Nb_octets_lus);

            string restemp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MyBuffer);
            restemp = restemp.Replace(Constants.vbCr, "");
            restemp = restemp.Replace(Constants.vbLf, "");
            restemp = restemp.Replace(Strings.ChrW(26).ToString(), "");

            byte[] MyTempArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(restemp);

            hashAlgorithm.TransformBlock(MyTempArray, 0, MyTempArray.Length, null, 0);

            MyTempArray = null;
        }
        hashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);
        btHashWithContext = hashAlgorithm.Hash;
    }

    return btHashWithContext;
}
```

Is there a method allowing to add padding to a hash after it's generated ?

Comment: "RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 encryption" is, as the name suggests, **not** a signature scheme, it's an encryption scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll correct my post. Is there any means of converting a PKCS#1.5 encryption result to a PKCS#1 result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this website :

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-systems?topic=cryptography-pkcs-1-hash-formats

If you add some extra bytes at the beginning of the hash value, you can obtain a result according to a PKCS#1 signature

The hex bytes for a SHA256 Hash are as following :

```
SHA-256
X'3031300D 06096086 48016503 04020105 000420'
```

In C# I just add those hex bytes this way :

```
public void Main()
{
    string hash = "3Z6TXNaRtoPP5kv5l4XBarx4GM+uH1M9rRK9iwRkKfY=";
    byte[] btHash = Convert.FromBase64String(hash);
    
    // Generates padding bytes to add at beginning of hash
    string hexString = "3031300D060960864801650304020105000420";
    byte[] btPadBytes = HexStringToByteArray(hexString);

    // Combines both byte arrays
    byte[] btCombined = ByteArrayCombine(bt, btHash);
    
    string hashWithPadding = Convert.ToBase64String(btCombined);
    
}

public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}

public static byte[] ByteArrayCombine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
    return ret;
}
```